# How to create POST rest api using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have printed data from an AngularJS controller to factory so client side has data for API, but when I post data to server side it's printing undefined `req.body`. Any idea what is missing in the code below?

I have `body-parser` module added to app.js

angularJsFactory.js

```
angular.module('App').factory('LogsFactory', function($http) {
    'use strict';
    return {
        addNewUser: function(user) {
            console.log('user in factory', user);
            return $http.post('/newUser', user);
        }
    }
});
```

Node-App.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile');
var async = require('async');
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var io = require('./app/io').initialize(server);
app.use(cookieParser());
require('./app/serverfiles/components/auth')(app);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

    app.post('/newUser',function(req,res){
        console.log(req.body);
    });
```

Comment: What is printing `console.log('user in factory', user);`?

Comment: Are you using Express?

Comment: @lealceldeiro  user in factory {"firstName":"John","lastName":"Strat","email":"abc@abc.com","_id":"id8976","type":"user","attuid":"kj897s","message":"user need access"}

Comment: @Aron yes i am using express

Comment: @Aron i have added my app dependencies into question

Comment: You haven't done `app.use(bodyParser())` anywhere

Comment: Thanks that was the problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget to have your Express app actually use the body parser.

```
app.use(bodyParser());
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the body-parser module to overcome this problem

```
app.use(bodyParser());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Express.js to be able handle POST requests you have to add to your code just:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

I suppose that's what you are looking for.